# if/else statements without comparison operators and curly braces

Tags: programming

I recently came across this code in a tutorial. The code works, but this form of syntax seems to differ quite a bit from https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/control-structure/if/, as it's lacking comparison operators and curly braces for statements. Can someone please run down why this works?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
lcd.setCursor(i, 1);
if (pressed[i])
  lcd.print("X");
else
  lcd.print(" ");

if (justpressed[i])
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
else
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
 }
```

Comment: Arduino uses C++ programming language with specific libraries and .ino file conversion to C++ http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

About the missing conditions, e.g.:

```
if (pressed[i])
```

If is supposed to be a boolean, this is the prefered way, as long as the boolean has value zero (0) when false and nonzero when true. It is the same as writing:

```
if (pressed[i] != 0)
```

It is not usual to do this for integers, only for booleans.

About the brackets: If you have only one statement the brackets can be omitted. But it is quite a bad programming practice, since sooner or later you add a statement, without the brackets added and you have a bug introduced.

If you really want to shorten it than instead of

```
if (justpressed[i])
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
else
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
```

use

```
digitalWrite(justpressed[i] ? HIGH : LOW);
```

This is called the [Ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C).

**update**

Using the remark of wondra but with the ternary operation your code can be

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    lcd.setCursor(i, 1);
    lcd.print   (     pressed    [i] ? "X"  : " ");
    digitalWrite(led, justpressed[i] ? HIGH : LOW);
}
```

Comment: Just for fun of it, even the printing if/else can be much shortened: `lcd.print(" X"[!!pressed[i]]);`

Comment: @wondra right ... but most have to read a few times to see why it works.. I would it change to lcd.print(pressed[i] ? "X" : " "); probably.

Comment: Sadly, fun =/= smart in most cases. Fully agree - if the code is to be ever maintained one should stick to the most straight-forward solution (whatever that is it expected to be for the poor fellow doing the code maintenance).

Comment: True, in the organization I work for the ternary operation is allowed, but only in trivial cases like that, if bigger expressiosn are taken into account the if/else should be used. Btw; to make it shorter you can probably even put everything in the for statement (not loop).

Comment: It's actually called the "Conditional Operator". It just so happens to be the only ternary operator.

Comment: @wondra I don't know arduino, but if this is really C++ like another comment said then you'd be passing a `char` instead of a string to `lcd.print()`. It's not a problem if `lcd.print` is a polymorphic method that is also made to work with `char`s, but that's not necessarily the case, so that could be a bug. Strive not to write simple ideas in a complex manner, but to write complex ideas in a simple manner.

Comment: Small nit-pick: shouldn't it be equal to saying `if (pressed[i] == 1)`, not `if (pressed[i] != 0)`?

Comment: @McMastery Actually it's not the same ... there is a convention (not always true, especially in C), that a boolean FALSE value is 0, and a TRUE value is non zero. In your case, if TRUE would be 255 it would go wrong.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Ah, sorry. I thought the convention was the other way around for some reason

Answer (score 4):

1. **if (something)** is the same as **if(something!=0)**, if condition is a non-zero value, it is considered as [fulfilled condition](https://www.le.ac.uk/users/rjm1/cotter/page_37.htm), read about the [Conditionals - The true or false story](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/3483/)
2. For single line statements you don't need to use curly braces. But using the braces makes the code more readable and the code is [less prone to errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193170/whats-the-purpose-of-using-braces-i-e-for-a-single-line-if-or-loop)

Comment: It's worth noting that curly braces on single-line statements can definitely help prevent some insidious bugs: remember [Apple's famous SSL bug](https://embeddedgurus.com/barr-code/2014/03/apples-gotofail-ssl-security-bug-was-easily-preventable/)? Curly braces almost certainly would have avoided that, or at least made it more clear where the error was.

Comment: @ke4ukz I think the fear of repeating that SSL bug is over stated. If you're going to use an inline `if` statement, do it ... in... line. Don't put it on a new line. `if (someEarlyExitCondition()) return;` never hurt anyone, if it was all in one line. The new line+indent that people put whenever they use inline if statements always confused me. It's just so unnecessary!

Comment: @Alexander I agree: inline for inline, curly braces for indenting/multiple lines